# How to get procedure,function,view,cursor names for respective table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get all the details respective to the table as mentioned in the title.
I tried, could get table name and view name but not all.

Comment: right click table and View Dependancy

Comment: That's good ...,want to get through query!!

Answer (score 0):

**For Query:**

```
sp_depends 'dbo.Employee'
```

**For UI:**

```
Right click table and View Dependancy
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get it done.

Method 1:

```
sp_depends 'dbo.TableName'    
GO
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT *  
FROM information_schema.routines ISR  
WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.TableName', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0  
GO
```

Method 3:

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, 
       referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent  
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.TableName', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT CLICK ON DBNAME -->TASK--> GENERATE SCRIPT--> CLICK NEXT -->YOU CAN SELECT ALL OBJECT (TABLE,VIEW,SP,FUNCTION, ETC) --> NEXT --> CHOOSE BROWSE WANT TO SAVE SCRIPT -->CLICK NEXT -->CLICK NEXT-->CLICK FINISH

THEN OPEN YOUR LOCATION SCRIPT!

-->IF YOU WANT TO GET RECORD ALL DATA<--

RIGHT CLICK ON DBNAME -->TASK--> GENERATE SCRIPT--> CLICK NEXT -->YOU CAN SELECT ALL OBJECT (TABLE,VIEW,SP,FUNCTION, ETC) --> NEXT -->CLICK ADVANCE-->YOU ARE FIND 'TYPE OF DATA TO SCRIPT' IN TAB GENERAL, THEN CHANGE STATUS AT COMBOBOX TO BE SCEMA AND DATA-->CLICK OK-->CHOOSE BROWSE WANT TO SAVE SCRIPT -->CLICK NEXT -->CLICK NEXT-->CLICK FINISH

Comment: CAPS is love, CAPS is life